# JavaScript when not to pass callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused when I should be passing callbacks to functions. For example,
`<div onMouseEnter={handleMouse} />` or `<div onMouseEnter={() => handleMouse()} />`
I didnt need the callback value that comes with onMouseEnter so I passed it as the second option and my boss said to do it like the first way. Im not sure why because would it just be passing on unused data?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an arrow function as a prop will cause creating a new function every time the render is called and it's an anti-pattern in react.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a callback with either approach.

The difference is that `handleMouse` always passes the existing `handleMouse` function and that `() => handleMouse()` creates a new function which does nothing except call `handleMouse` … and it creates another new function *every time* the component is rendered.